# Can I replace the backing Fusion Sync for my dataset?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-fusion-sheet

I am having issues with my current Fusion Sync so I want to swap out the backing Fusion Sync for the dataset. I do not want to create a new dataset because it would have a new RID and I would have to refactor all code and analyses that use the dataset as an input. Can I replace the backing Fusion Sync for my dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the process to achieve this:

- Create a new Fusion sheet with the relevant data
- Navigate to the existing/buggy Fusion Sync and click `Stop syncing`
  [image]
- Go to the output dataset → details → job spec → Edit → delete
  [image]
  [image]
- Go the the copied sheet, create a table and sync it to the master of that dataset
  [image]
  [image]